# How to remove 'Subscribe' field from Luma footer

Tags: magento2, footer

I've gotten rid of the links but '**subscribe**' field is still there. How is this referenced? Meaning I want it gone, not just hidden. Seems like this should be easy but can't figure it out - Thanks.

Comment: Did you create a custom theme?

Answer (score 9):

This block is defined in the Magento Newsletter module. So you can remove the block entirely via xml layout file.
Create this file in your own theme or add to it.

> app/design/frontend/YourCompany/your_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This will remove the footer subscribe form from every page of your site.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Although for some reason, the only default.xml I can get to work is housed in 'vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/'

Comment: @user51798 Your changes with any file in the vendor folder will not be permanent. The next time you update Magento your changes will be lost. You need to [create your own Magento theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) and use it to extend and override blocks like this.

Answer (score 0):

put below code in default.xml inside your theme folder

```
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
```